# How use Bulk insert csv to sql server with datetime format correct?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, date-format, bulkinsert

i want use bulk insert file csv insert to **SQL Server 2012**. same column have datetime but use bulk insert datetime format not work and **i not use SSIS**.

**Example Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[scanindex_test](
    [request_no] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
    [request_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [id_card] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [firstname] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [surname] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

**Query Sql Server 2012:**

```
declare 
    @path      varchar(255),
    @sql       varchar(5000)           

SET @path = 'C:\Test\TESTFILE.csv'    

set @sql = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[scanindex_test] FROM ''' + @path + ''' 
      ' + '     WITH (      
                CODEPAGE=''RAW'',           
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

**when i run query it's error:**

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 2 (request_date).
Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

**Example Data in CSV File**

```
request_no | request_date  | id_card  | firstname    | surname
1          | 12/7/2017     | 1122     | AA           | BB
2          | 12/7/2017     | 4399     | SS           | EE
3          | 13/7/2017     | 5599     | QQ           | KK
```

**Result when run query:**

```
request_no | request_date            | id_card  | firstname | surname
1          | 2017-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 1122     | AA        | BB
2          | 2017-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 4399     | SS        | EE
3  >> Error, because it's look datetime format: 2017-13-07 (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

**but I want result datetime format (YYYY-MM-DD) correct:**

```
request_no | request_date            | id_card | firstname | surname
1          | 2017-07-12 00:00:00.000 | 1122    | AA        | BB
2          | 2017-07-12 00:00:00.000 | 4399    | SS        | EE
3          | 2017-07-13 00:00:00.000 | 5599    | QQ        | KK
```

Please Help me. Thanks advance ;)

Comment: First, SQL Server's import and ETL tool is SSIS, not bcp or BULK INSERT. Those are meant for *fast* bulk operations. Date parsing or any kind of parsing isn't fast. In this case you may be able to use a format file as shown in [Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server) and specify a collation for the date fields that matches the date format.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have to import the file into a staging table and parse the date fields. You wouldn't have to do that though if you used SSIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `DATEFORMAT` to `DMY`.  Adding the following to the top of your script should work:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
```

So your full script should be:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

declare 
    @path      varchar(255),
    @sql       varchar(5000)           

SET @path = 'C:\Test\TESTFILE.csv'    

set @sql = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[scanindex_test] FROM ''' + @path + ''' 
      ' + '     WITH (      
                CODEPAGE=''RAW'',           
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: As far as I know, DATEFORMAT doesn't work with BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

It works with Bulk Insert:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TRX]
        FROM 'C:\..\trx2.txt'
            WITH
    (           
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
                FIRSTROW = 2
    )
PRINT 'BULK INSERT [TRX2]'
GO
```